# Using has_many method in an ActiveResource object to relate to local ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I want to use an `ActiveResource` object to map `Users` from a service but I have local data that I want to associate with these `Users`

I have code that looks something like this:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://my/api"

  has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :notifications_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notifications, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**notification.rb:**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end
```

If `ActiveResource` doesn't support `has_many` then how should I go about getting around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveResource does support associations but they should be external resource as well. So in your case it doesn't apply.

I think your requirement is legit and would suggest manually construct methods for them. For example:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://my/api"

  def notifications
    Notification.where(user_id: self.id)
  end
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  def user
    User.find(self.user_id)
  end

  def recipient
    User.find(self.recipient_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahhh ok. I guess I'll have to try this. I'll +1 for now and accept later If this ends up being a solid solution.